# Remote virtual displays

Tags: xorg, remote

I have two machines in local network, e.g. `192.168.8.30 (1)` and `192.168.8.31 (2)` and for each connected 2 displays.
I want to use all of display like a physically connected to one of machine.
Can I use one X server for every displays ? or use "same functional" by another ways.

Comment: I created somewhere a big, virtual memory-based X server with the needed resolution (around 6000x1200 or so ?), runned a vnc server on that, and used full-screen vnc clients to map the needed parts of them to the actual desktop.